# Multi language support in Client and Server at once

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, multilingual

I'm building in `ASP.NET MVC 4` a site. While sometimes I return a full View and sometimes I call `Ajax` from a View, get some data and build a new page with JavaScript.

for example :

```
 myDiv.append("<div class=\"test\">some text </div>");
```

I want to support in multi language, if it was only on client side without `ASP.NET` views
I would be using `JavaScript` to load files by the language

```
 english.js
 -------------------------
 var home = 'home';


 russian.js
 ------------------------
 var home = 'дом';
```

How can I support multi language so it will work with `JavaScript` on client side and while rendering a View in `ASP.NET` page?

Comment: `var home = 'dom'` is incorrect. Good one is `var home = 'дом'` :)

Comment: This could be polish language file instead russian ;)

Comment: file name is `russian.js` :))

Comment: But could be polish.js :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you render localized strings right in a view? 
smth like:

```
<script>
    var home = '@SomeResource.SomeStringValue'
</script>
```

or even include js file depending on client language?

E.g. You have some resource file named `LocalizedStrings.resx` with default language. For different languages you have files named `LocalizedStrings.en-US.resx`, `LocalizedStrings.kk-KZ.resx` etc...

In a view you do following:

```
@Html.RenderPartial('MyLocalizedView')
```

and `MyLocalizedView` itself looks like:

```
<script>
    var home = '@LocalizedStrings.Home';
    var street = '@LocalizedStrings.Street';
    var wtf = '@LocalizedStrings.Wtf';
    ...
</script>
```

So when the main view is rendered you already have all js variables initialized with proper localized values.
Of course you need to make sure your current culture is set to proper value, like:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

I don't know how you control it, I'd do it in `global.asax` depending on domain extension

Comment: could you give an example how you combine it once in client side and once in server View?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a custom http handler for this which dynamically generates all my Resources as an js object.

The resulting object for the resource named as JS_PageTitle may look like:

```
var resources = { PageTitle: "page title en" }.
```

The http handler implementation:

```
            public class JavascriptResourceHandler : IHttpHandler
            {
                #region IHttpHandler Members

                public bool IsReusable
                {
                    // Return false in case your Managed Handler cannot be reused for another request.
                    // Usually this would be false in case you have some state information preserved per request.
                    get { return true; }
                }

                public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
                {
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();            
                    sb.Append(" var resources = { ");
                    var properties = typeof (WebRes).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("JS_")).ToList();

                    for (int i=0; i<properties.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var property = properties[i];

                        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                        {
                            sb.Append(property.Name.Replace("JS_", string.Empty));
                            sb.Append(":");
                            sb.Append("'");
                            sb.Append(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode((string)property.GetValue(null, null)));
                            sb.Append("'");
                            if (i != properties.Count - 1)
                                sb.Append(",");
                        }
                    }

                    sb.Append("};");

                    context.Response.Clear();
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
                    context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
                }

                #endregion
            }
```

The configuration entry in the web.config

```
  <add name="JavascriptResourceHandler" verb="GET" path="JavascriptResourceHandler.axd" type="Web.Infrastructure.HttpHandlers.JavascriptResourceHandler, Web, Version=1.0.*, Culture=neutral" />
```

Then reference it from the _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/JavascriptResourceHandler.axd"></script>
```